# I do not want edit contact of address book

Tags: iphone

I am able to add contact to address book  now after adding i see details of contact.I do not want edit button to edit contact. (i want it in only read mode). and also do't want use ABUnknownPersonViewController. How can i do this? 
Please help me.

Thanks,
Vilas979

Answer (score 0):

The [Quick Contacts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample code from the Apple documents library provides a good idea how to use ABUnknownPersonViewController.  Specifically, look for QuickContactsViewController.m and the pragma mark `Add data to an existing person`

Comment: Thanks, i know "Quick Contact" but they used ABUnknownPersonViewController , i do't want use that. and i want changes in address book which is on my iphone.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I misread and thought you said you _did_ want to use ABUnknownPersonViewController.  I'm not positive about this, but I believe you should be able to look at the records without being able to edit them by setting the `isReadOnly` property for the ABRecord you wish to view

Comment: isReadOnly property for the ABRecord used only of mac not for iphone. Because i not getting ABRecord and it property isRead only in iphone ios 4.3 .if you any other answer please sent me & Thanks for Reply.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before, but why not use ABPersonViewController (the usual instance you'd see) and set `allowsEditing` to NO?  That should do the trick